# Auto resize to fill all multi panels

Tags: c#, resize, fill

How to size all panels as fill in form1 window without changing panels size? I searched on Google. very difficult to find. That why i want to help. like in below Thanks.

If 3 panels this will be resized:

[image]

4 Panels:

[image]

5 Panels:

[image]

9 Panels:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a FlowLayoutPanel. Insert in your form and set Dock=Fill in the designer. Add this const to your form:

```
private const int PanelSize = 200;
```

In the constructor:

```
this.flowLayoutPanel1.Resize += this.OnFlowLayoutPanel1_Resize;
this.OnFlowLayoutPanel1_Resize(this.flowLayoutPanel1, EventArgs.Empty);
```

And use this method to create/destroy the panels:

```
private void OnFlowLayoutPanel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // At least, one panel
    var columns = Math.Max(1, this.flowLayoutPanel1.Width / (double)PanelSize);
    var rows = Math.Max(1, this.flowLayoutPanel1.Height / (double)PanelSize);

    var panelsCount = this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count;
    var requiredPanelsCount = rows * columns;
    var diff = requiredPanelsCount - panelsCount;
    if (diff > 0)
    {
        // We need more panels: create it
        for (int i = 0; i < diff; i++)
        {
            var panel = new Panel
            {
                Size = new Size(PanelSize, PanelSize),
                TabIndex = this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count, 
                BackColor = GetBackColor()
            };
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Remove unneeded panels
        for (int i = 0; i < diff; i++)
        {
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.RemoveAt(
                this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I have used this method to set a color:

```
private Color GetBackColor()
{
    var colors = new[] 
    { 
        Color.Black, Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue, Color.White
    };
    var index = this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count % colors.Length;
    return colors[index];
}
```

Adapt it to your needs.

If you need fill entire form, you must work with a variable PanelSize. Use a minimum and maximum size for the panels instead a fixed value.

I'm creating/removing Panels to fill entire space. If you only need fixed panels in the form, you don't need the resize event. The FlowLayoutControl do what you need.

Comment: Thank you for help. How i set limit panels count and add scrollbar in flowlayoutpanel1 control?

Comment: In the designer you can set AutoScroll=true. You don't need limit the number of panels on the FlowLayoutPanel control. Think about this control like an array or list: you add controls into it (or remove). If you can limit the number of panels, use Controls collection to know how many Panels are you inserted. At first, I though that your question wanted fill the whole control, my example is not the best but show you how to do it. You don't need the resize event, remove it. Simply add the number of panels that you need.

Comment: I want to ask as a last question. How can fill panels in flowlayoutpanel when resized Form1?

Comment: I don't understand. My original answer, in the resize, calculate the number of rows and columns with the current flowlayout size for panels of 200x200 and check how many panels are needed to fill the space. Also remove panels when size become smaller. Is this what you want?